# Чем может быть полезен setvesablank?

Tags: linux

Собственно для чего он нужен и почему ничего не происходит при его использовании?

```
$ sudo setvesablank
usage: setvesablank ON|on|off

$ sudo setvesablank
$
```

Откуда это

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/sbin/setvesablank 
kbd: /usr/sbin/setvesablank
```

https://github.com/legionus/kbd

Что это

```
Description-en: Linux console font and keytable utilities
 This package allows you to set up the Linux console, change the font,
 resize text mode virtual consoles and remap the keyboard.
```

Comment: а где ты его нашёл?

Comment: Не думаю что должно что-то происходить сразу, это больше похоже на включение/выключение функции энергосбережения в целом.

Answer (score 2):

Код этого дела:

```
arg.ten   = 10;
arg.onoff = 0;

if (!strcmp(argv[1], "on"))
    arg.onoff = 1;
else if (!strcmp(argv[1], "ON"))
    arg.onoff = 2;

if (ioctl(fd, TIOCLINUX, &arg)) {
    kbd_error(EXIT_FAILURE, errno, "setvesablank: TIOCLINUX");
}

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

Так говорят мануалы:

```
   TIOCLINUX, subcode=10
          Handles  the Power Saving feature of the new generation of moni‐
          tors.  VESA screen blanking mode is set to argp[1],  which  gov‐
          erns what screen blanking does:

          0: Screen blanking is disabled.

          1: The  current  video adapter register settings are saved, then
             the controller is programmed to turn off  the  vertical  syn‐
             chronization  pulses.   This  puts the monitor into "standby"
             mode.  If your monitor has an Off_Mode timer,  then  it  will
             eventually power down by itself.

          2: The  current  settings  are saved, then both the vertical and
             horizontal synchronization pulses are turned off.  This  puts
             the monitor into "off" mode.  If your monitor has no Off_Mode
             timer, or if you want your monitor to power down  immediately
             when  the blank_timer times out, then you choose this option.
             (Caution: Powering down frequently will damage the  monitor.)
             (Since Linux 1.1.76.)
```

Таким образом, если я правильно понимаю, то эта команда устанавливает режим гашения консоли следующим образом: "off" — не использовать VESA-compatible console blanking; "on" — выключить кадровый синхроимпульс, что должно переводить монитор в standby; "ON" — выключить кадровый и строчный синхроимпульсы, что должно переводить монитор в off.

Мануал говорит «governs what screen blanking does», то есть она вроде как не должна вызывать немедленного выключения экрана.

Comment: Что подразумеваете под "гашением консоли"?

Comment: Консоль. Она гасится, то есть становится нельзя прочесть и даже увидеть то, что на ней написано. Она может просто забиваться пробелами и становиться чёрной, а может гасить монитор. Рассматриваемый случай - именно про гашение монитора.

Comment: Можете написать воспроизводимый пример, что нужно сделать, чтобы проверить этот случай?

Comment: Переключились в консоль, позапускали так, так и эдак, подождали после каждого запуска по полчаса не отходя от монитора, сравнили результаты. Я не знаю, сколько и где посмотреть таймаут бланкера консоли.

Answer (score 2):

Как уже сказано в соседнем ответе, `setvesablank` просто делает `ioctl` `TIOCLINUX` с кодом 10 (он же `TIOCL_SETVESABLANK`), что устанавливает «режим *очистки*» (*blanking*) консоли.

То же самое делает утилита `setterm` из состава `util-linux` с параметром `--powersave {off|hsync|vsync|powerdown}`. Типовое применение выглядит как-то так:

```
setterm --blank 5 --powerdown 2 --powersave vsync
```

Что задаёт примерно следующий алгоритм работы драйвера виртуально терминала:

- Через 5 минут бездействия очистить содержимое экрана.
- Ещё через 2 минуты отключить вертикальный синхросигнал, что переведёт монитор в suspend-режим.

Кстати говоря, в `man ioctl_console` ошибка, на самом деле параметры `TIOCL_SETVESABLANK`:

- `0`, `off` — производит только очистку изображения на экране, должен делать его чёрным.
- `1`, `vsync`, `on`  — выключает vsync, переводя монитор в «suspend»-режим.
- `2`, `hsync` — выключает hsync, переводя монитор в «standby»-режим.
- `3`, `powerdown` — выключает оба сигнала, что соответствует отключению монитора.

Это видно в исходниках и [ядра](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.2/source/include/uapi/linux/fb.h#L296), и [`setterm`](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/term-utils/setterm.c#L280). Эти четыре режима отражение спецификации [DPMS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA_Display_Power_Management_Signaling), правда `vsync` и `hsync` переставлены местами.

#### Почему эффект может несколько отличаться от ожидаемого/описанного выше.

Во-первых, в полной мере DPMS был актуален во времена седой ламповой древности с ЭЛТ-мониторами. Для них имеет смысл различать режим ожидание с отключением электронной пушки и полноценное отключение спирали накала катода т.к. в последнем случа потом придётся долго ждать пока прогреется кинескоп. Но сегодня для LCD-экранов включение происходит почти моментально и для них  выпустили стандарт «DPM», в котором говорится, что они должны реагировать на переход во все режимы энергосбережения как на `powerdown`. Так что, чтобы увидеть разницу между `vsync`, `hsync` и `powerdown` придётся достать с антресоли (или найти на помойке) старого доброго друга с кинескопом.

Во-вторых, в linux работа консоли обеспечивается несколькими разными драйверами, которые немного по разному подходят к тому о чём их просят. В точности следует тому что описано выше старая добрая vga-консоль, а что будет происходить во фреймбуферной определяется драйвером соответствующего фреймбуфера и тут каждый делает кто-во-что горазд:

- [реализация по умолчанию](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5-rc1/source/drivers/video/fbdev/core/fbcon.c#L2370), которая используется в `vesafb` только очищает экран и ничего не делает с монитором.
- fb эмуляция в drm игнорирует отключение энергосбережения и при задании `setterm --powersave off` [переходит](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.2/source/drivers/gpu/drm/drm_fb_helper.c#L351) в `standby` аналогично `hsync`, а на современных мониторах просто отключает их.
- `uvesafb` [будет](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.2/source/drivers/video/fbdev/uvesafb.c#L1104) корректно работать только для значений `off` и `powerdown`, а для `vsync` и `hsync` будет фолбек на реализацию по умолчанию с ручной очисткой фреймбуфера.
- `nvidiafb` напротив, например, [делает](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.2/source/drivers/video/fbdev/nvidia/nvidia.c#L927) всё как написано.